# How to redirect to another page when the button is clicked on React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a google map with a report button and I cant figure out how to make the page redirect to another page when the button with class "report-btn" is clicked? I tried to used  but it didnt work and Im not sure how to go about implementing this.

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: {}, 
    selectedPlace: {}, 
  };

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true,
    });
  onClose = (props) => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: 40.75901,
          lng: -73.984474,
        }}
      >
        <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick} name={"S Train - 42 Street"} />
        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={this.onClose}
        >
          <div>
            <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
            <button className="report-btn">Report</button>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `react router` with `Link`. Follow this https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: If you meant to say another component, then use react router.

Answer (score 0):

You have `2 solutions`, use `react-router-dom` or `window.location.href/replace`

```js
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

**you should use**

```
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';


  return (
    <Link to={"/somewhereyoulike}>
        <Button>
          somthiong
        </Button>
    </Link>

)
```